# ODSI + weblogic = JDBC problem

Tags: oracle10g, weblogic, jdbc

I'm currently developing a web service using ODSI through Oracle Workshop for WebLogic (ex AquaLogic).
I created a datasource on weblogic using the driver **"Oracle thin driver 10g"**, the test succeed on WebLogic. (My Database is Oracle 10 10.2.0.1.0)
The problem occours when I try to create the Phisical Data Service in the Oracle Workshop. I choose the following options:

```
Data source type = Relational
Data source = [THE CORRECT NAME OF THE SOURCE SET ON WEBLOGIC]
Database type = ???
```

Aqualogic, doesn't allow me to select the database type. I guess is a problem related to the driver set on weblogic... but I ain't sure.
Does someone know the nature of my problem ? 
Tnx

Answer (score 1):

The database needs to be up and running and accessible through the JDBC Data Source. Since it is not accessible, ODSI cannot connect to it to determine the database type.